# I have written code for calling javascript functtion in asp.net but while debugging the code its showing some error

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Send" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-oim pull-right" 
                OnClientClick="disableSend();" meta:resourcekey="SendResource1"
                OnClick="Send_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```

I have written this code and it is calling a function in JavaScript `disableSend` but while debugging it is showing an error:

> onclick="showDiv()";-->showdiv is undefined

How to resolve this?

Comment: Share the code.

Comment: Yes, please. We can't help you if we don't know your code. It looks like you don't load the file that includes the `showDiv()`-function correctly.

Comment: So to clarify the above ASP.NET code is producing html with `onclick="showDiv()"`? Also is that `;` actually outside the attribute value?